# For portable shell scripts without long options, can getopt always be used?

Tags: shell, scripting, posix, sh

I need to write POSIX shell scripts for many platforms and just discovered that at least one of them does not have `getopts` but it does have `getopt`.

Is `getopt` supported everywhere? If not, where is it not?

I don't have any 'long options'. I do have options which take no argument, others which take an integer or a string (usually a path without spaces), and other positional arguments (all placed after the options since I was previously relying on `getopts`).

As long as I don't need long options, can I always rely on `getopt`? If not, when not?

Edit: I read a quote from a FAQ about how we should just forget `getopt` even exists but it was followed by [an answer which appeared to disprove the rationale for the quote](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/62961/114970).

Stéphane Chazelas wrote (emphasis mine) "`getopt` is a traditional command that comes from System V long before Linux was ever released. `getopt` **was never standardised.** None of POSIX, Unix, or Linux (LSB) ever standardized the `getopt` command."

Is there a way to use `getopt` on all three? Like a minimal feature set which is common to all three?

Thanks!

Comment: If it doesn't have [`getopts`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/getopts.html), it's not a POSIX platform. Would the guilty platform be Solaris, by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument against `getopt` is against versions not from util-linux (i.e. "traditional versions of `getopt`" from the given [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035#getopts) link).

The answer you linked to misses that context (I'd almost argue intentionally misses it as the quoted snippet starts **immediately** after the crucially important context word "traditional". And follows the sentence that explains what "traditional" in that context means.)

util-linux getopt supports them, traditional getopt does not. That makes it entirely non-portable.

I cannot speak to the general portability of `getopt` beyond that but I would expect that its basic functionality is likely to work just about everywhere (and more to the point unless you know your code is going to run on "obscure" environments it likely isn't going to).

That being said the non-`getopt` solutions that should be entirely portable are not particularly complicated and should be able handle everything you care to write the code for.